# JsonIgnoreType only looks at field's declared type?

Tags: java, json, jackson

All,

I'm trying to use `@JsonIgnoreType` with Jackson 2.7.3.  It appears to work fine as long as the field containing the type is declared to be of the same type as the actual instance I assign to it, but if the field is declared to be a super type, then it doesn't work.

For example, with this code:

```
public class Sub extends Super {

  private String value = null;

  public Sub() {}

  public Sub(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

public class Foo {

  private Super value = null;

  public Foo() {}

  public Foo(Super value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Super getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Super value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Then I try to serialize something like this:

```
 new Foo(new Sub("123"));
```

It doesn't matter whether I use the JsonIgnoreType annotation or mixin, the output will be something like

```
{"value":{"value":"123"}}
```

If instead I change the variable declaration in class Foo to this:

```
private Sub value = null;  // declared Sub instead of Super
```

Then I get the expected output:

```
{}
```

This seems just plain dumb, like polymorphism isn't a thing.  For my use case I can't ignore the superclass because that's too broad.  I also would prefer to not care where the type Sub appears.  Whether it's in Foo, Bar, Baz, or anywhere else, I don't want to serialize it.

What can I do to get Jackson to ignore the actual type I'm using instead of looking at the field's declared type?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That works as expected as far I can tell. If you instruct Jackson to ignore `Sub` class, it has no reason to also ignore an object of `Super` class when it happens to have been created as a an instance of `Sub`.

You can create a property filter to conditionally ignore the `value` field of `Foo` when it is an instance of `Sub`:

```
class SubFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {
  @Override
  public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
    if (!writer.getName().equals("value") || !(((Foo) pojo).getValue() instanceof Sub)) {
      writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
    }
  }
}
```

and remember to annotate `Foo` (or use mixin):

```
@JsonFilter("subFilter")
class Foo {
```

and also use the filter to create a `FilterProvider` and then use that to create an `ObjectWriter`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(new Sub("123"));
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("subFilter", new SubFilter());
String json = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(foo);
```

`value` will still get serialized if it was created as instance of `Super` or another child class.
You can read more in [this blog](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I updated my question to clarify that I want to exclude this type anywhere it appears without having to enumerate all of the locations.

Comment: Philosophically, what you call "works" I call "broken."  (-:  When java invokes a method, it uses the method impl in the instance itself or its nearest ancestor and doesn't care at all what type the variable holding the ref to the object was declared to be.  It seems pretty incongruous that Jackson doesn't do the same.